# Convert TB, Gb and MB excel

Tags: excel, converters

I have a problem with converting my data to the same unit and need some input from you.

I have a table of data usages over 3 years. The data i in MB, GB and TB. I would like to have it all on GB. I tried to use:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(IF(RIGHT(D5;2)="TB";LEFT(D5;LEN(D5)-3)*1024;IF(RIGHT(D5;2)="MB";LEFT(D5;LEN(D5)-3)/1024)));0)
```

All i get returned is 0 or if i remove iferror i get #value

Here a link of some of the data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPTLV.png

Comment: There's not enough information here. If I were you i'd use VBA since it'd be a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to multiply the output of `LEFT()` function which is text. You need to convert it first, then multiply. Also check the decimal separator in your system. It might be comma, not period. Then it might also cause errors.

Here's a better formula:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(D5,LEN(D5)-3))*IF(RIGHT(D5,2)="TB",1024,IF(RIGHT(D5,2)=GB,1,1/1024)),0)
```

You can also use `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace decimal separators to what you need:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(D5,LEN(D5)-3),".",","))*IF(RIGHT(D5,2)="TB",1024,IF(RIGHT(D5,2)=GB,1,1/1024)),0)
```